# Get contents of all divs with same class name, change CSS based on their value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to "decorate" some divs based on their content.

There are many divs on my page, and the ones I wish to target all have the same classname of `.gains`

If the contents of a `.gains` div is = 0, make it grey. If it's more then 0, make it green. If it's less than 0, make it red.

I've attempted to write something but I am not sure how to iterate through all the divs rather than just grabbing the data for every one into one string.

```
window.onload = decorateGains();
function decorateGains(){
    var gain_loss = $(".gains").text();
    console.log("gains_loss = " + gain_loss);
    if (gain_loss < 0){
        // make red
    }else if (gain_loss == 0){
        // make grey
    }else if (gain_loss > 0){
        // make green
    }
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row row-1">
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">Nov 14 9:30am</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">1,567</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data gains">1567</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-2">
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">Nov 14 4:30pm</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">1,566</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data gains">-1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use specific styles to apply if your conditions are met. Also, remember to convert the text into number.

***See this snippet:***

```js
decorateGains();
function decorateGains() {
    $(".gains").each(function() {     // loop thru all .gains
        var num = +($(this).text());  // get text and convert to number
        if (num > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("green"); // apply appropriate class
        }
        if (num < 0) {
            $(this).addClass("red");   // apply appropriate class
        }
      
      // no need to check for equality as that will be default.
    });
}
```

```css
.gains {
    color: #ccc;
}
.red {
    background-color: #f00;
    color: #fff;
}
.green {
    background-color: #0f0;
    color: #fff;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row row-1">
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">Nov 14 9:30am</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">1,567</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data gains">1567</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-2">
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">Nov 14 4:30pm</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">1,566</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data gains">0</div>
</div>
<div class="row row-3">
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">Nov 14 4:30pm</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data">1,566</div>
    <div class="cell cell-1 data gains">-1</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use each in jquery

```
 $(".gains").each(function() {

   var gain_loss = parseInt($(this).text());
   console.log("gains_loss = " + gain_loss);
if (gain_loss < 0){
    // make red
}else if (gain_loss == 0){
    // make grey
}else if (gain_loss > 0){
    // make green
}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".gains").each(function () {
    var value = $(this).text();
    $(this).addClass((value == 0) ? "grey" : (value > 0) ? "green" : "red");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/kjo37t52/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

`css()` jQuery method accepts a function as second param, you could use:

```
$(".gains").css('color', function(){
    return +$(this).text() > 0 ? "green": +$(this).text() === 0 ? "grey" : "red";
});
```

You could instead add a specific class.